# Unable to style an anchor tag? Someone explain why?

Tags: html, css

> **Start here:** [scroll to bottom footer](http://www.designobvio.us/smartklubben/category/resources)

I'm unable to create a hover effect on the footer anchors. The only way I've accomplished this is inline:

```
<a style="color:#6bc2ef;" ... >Company</a>
```

I feel so stupid... Anyone know why I'm unable to edit the style of these footer anchors?
I just want to add a class so I can make a hover effect

Example of footer links:

```
<a class="footA" href="http://www.designobvio.us/smartklubben/company">Company</a>
```

Example of CSS:

```css
.footA:hover {
  color:#6bc2ef;
}
```

Feels as if somethings is blocking me from editing the CSS. Either that, or I don't know how to nest properly...

Example of CSS

> http://designobvio.us/smartklubben/wp-content/themes/SchoolManagementClub/css/style.css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this rule:

```
#footer p a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

which is more specific than the rule which you're trying to apply.

Read here: http://www.standardista.com/css3/css-specificity/

You could do this:

```
#footer a {
    color: #fff;
}

#footer a.footA {
    color: #6bc2ef;
}
```

Now, your rule is more specific (because it contains an additional class selector).

Comment: @MatthewHarwood Btw, if you're wondering how I figured this out... I just inspected the anchor element in [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) - the ["Style" tab](https://getfirebug.com/css) provides a list of CSS rules that apply to the anchor.

Comment: This is a [test](http://code.google.com/p/es-lab/wiki/Talks#Changes_to_ECMAScript,_Part_2:_Harmony_Highlights_-_proxies_and)

Answer (score 1):

Your rule for `#footer p a` has higher CSS specificity than your `.footA:hover` therefor it is being ignored. You could use a selector like `#footer .footA:hover` instead, to increase the specificity.

You can read a lot more about how CSS specificity works and how to calculate which rule will apply [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you currently have:

```
a:hover .footA {
    color: #06e;
}
```

What you have in your post will work fine—it's just not working because you're not using it.

```
a.footA:hover {
    color: #06e;
}
```

Also, you have this line overriding that hover code:

```
#footer p a {color:#fff;}
```

This permanently sets the color of any `a` element in any state (hover, focus, etc).